# Changing state of object via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, state-machine

I am facing a problem with usage of state_machine. I can't find out how to change state of object(trip) in show page via AJAX. I'm newbie in rails and web developement, so if it's possible to write an simple exmaple it will be the best explanation.

**trip.rb**

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :content, :title

 state_machine :state, initial: :draft do

  state :draft
  state :published

  event :publish do
    transition :draft => :published
  end

  event :hide do
    transition :published => :draft
  end
 end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= button_to 'publish', action: :publish %>
<%= button_to 'hide', action: :hide%>

<h3><%= @trip.title %></h3>
<p><%= @trip.content%></p>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: @phoet I just want to know how to change state of trip from "draft" to "published" and vise versa at show page using AJAX

Comment: then "just" use google! there are millions of examples for using ajax with rails out there.

Comment: @phoet, sorry for this silly questions, I'm embarrased, but I really can't figure out how to change states using events via web pages and particularly using AJAX

Comment: watch those for the start http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate your question & will give you an answer. After all, everyone has to start somewhere!

---

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :trip do 
    post :publish
    post :hide
end
```

Generates the URLs: `domain.com/trips/:id/publish` & `domain.com/trips/:id/hide`

---

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/trips_controller.rb
def publish
    task = Task.find(params[:id])
    task.publish!

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end

def hide
    task = Task.find(params[:id])
    task.hide!

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

---

**View**

```
<%= button_to 'publish', action: :publish, remote: :true, method: :post %>
<%= button_to 'hide', action: :hide,  remote: :true, method: :post %>

<h3><%= @trip.title %></h3>
<p><%= @trip.content%></p>
```

---

**JS**

```
#app/views/trips/publish.js.erb
// your JS here
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I got the main idea. But when I'm trying to use this buttons I get error `No route matches [POST] "/trips/1"`

I also changed a bit your code
`<%= button_to 'publish', @trip, action: :publish, remote: :true, method: :post %>
<%= button_to 'hide', @trip, action: :hide,  remote: :true, method: :post %>` to make **View** work.

Comment: I think the new problem is the button path - you've just passed the instance var. I think we should use this: `<%= button_to 'publish', trip_publish_path(@trip.id), remote: :true, method: :post %>` & `<%= button_to 'hide', trip_hide_path(@trip.id), remote: :true, method: :post %>`

Comment: hmmmm - could you post your `button_to` rendered HTML by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly what need to post `<form action="/trips/1/hide" class="button_to" method="post"><div><input type="submit" value="hide"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="TkjdrgQeN8Z/TPXBGcGBQ6f5ZA8UDUZioKtlp7Hi8no="></div></form>`

Comment: That's okay! I just wanted to see `/trips/1/hide`

Comment: This *should* work to me - perhaps it's the button that's causing the problem?

Comment: Here is my routes `trip_publish POST   /trips/:trip_id/publish(.:format)   trips#publish
trip_hide POST   /trips/:trip_id/hide(.:format)trips#hide
trips GET    /trips(.:format)trips#index
POST   /trips(.:format)trips#create
new_trip GET /trips/new(.:format)trips#new
edit_trip GET    /trips/:id/edit(.:format)           trips#edit
trip GET    /trips/:id(.:format) trips#show`
in hide and publish action i got /trips/:trip_id/publish instead of /trips/:id/publish
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I havn't coped with routes trouble yet. But I appreciate your help. Your answers help me a lot. Thank you!